# CSS Positioning and Display Order

Tags: css

I have a block of HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li class="nav">c</li>
  <li class="nav">d</li>
</ul>
```

and a CSS ruleset:

```
ul li {
 display: inline;
}

li.nav {
 float: right;
}
```

which are not behaving to my intentions: I want it displayed like so:

```
ab                                      cd
```

but instead it's

```
ab                                      dc
```

the difference being the displayed order of elements. How do I have the list items of class "nav" be displayed in their syntactical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by separating the list into two and `float`ing them to their respective positions. I wrapped the two lists with a `div` and applied [`overflow: auto`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) to it. My final CSS code looked like this:

```
ul li {
 display: inline
}

div.post-info-wrap {
 overflow: auto
}

ul.post-info {
 float: left
}

ul.nav {
 float: right
}
```

and my markup like:

```
<div class="post-info-wrap">
  <ul class="post-info">
    <li/>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li/>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, the obvious quick fix is to just reverse the order of the elements in the list:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li class="nav">d</li>
  <li class="nav">c</li>
</ul>
```

I'm guessing what happens is that whenever the rendering engine encounters an element with `float:right` it pushes that element as far to the right as possible. So it first encounters the "c" and pushes that all the way over to the right, then it encounters the "d" and pushes that as far right as possible - but the "c" is already occupying the rightmost spot, so "d" stays to its left. Essentially, the elements are laid out in right-to-left order rather than left-to-right order.

Another option, I think, would be to divide the elements into two lists and just apply the `float: right` style to the second list as a whole (i.e. to the `<ul>` element).

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
ul li {
 display: inline;
}

ul.nav {
 float: right;
}
```

That way the list itself would float to the right margin but the order of the elements in it wouldn't be reversed.

Comment: This fixes this problem but creates a new one: the list items are not horizontally aligned. cd is placed one level lower than ab.

Comment: you can add the css style ul { display: inline; } to fix that, and then wrap the <ul>'s in a <div> tag to make them block-level objects again (if necessary)

Answer (score 1):

If you want c & d to be displayed in a block at the right, you'll have to put them inside one block element, not setting the `float` attribute on both.
I don't think that list elements like `<li>` are the right choice for your intention. You don't want to display a single list, so you may try using two lists (where one of them has the `float` attribute) or just simple `<div>` elements.

Comment: This fixes this problem but creates a new one: the list items are not horizontally aligned. cd is placed one level lower than ab.

Answer (score 1):

So actually you want a nav list and some other list? Why not use 2 lists?

```
<ul class="other">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
 </ul>
<ul class="nav">
 <li>c</li>
 <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

And css:

```
ul li {
display: inline;
}

.other{
float:left;
}

.nav {
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Float the `ul` where you want the content/container situated and float the li in the order you want it displayed.

```
<div id="myblock">
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myblock ul {
   display:inline;
   float:right;
}

#myblock li {
   float:left;
 }
```

The opposite (float to the left but in reverse order)

```
#myblock ul {
   display:inline;
   float:left;
}

#myblock li {
   float:right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ul {
        text-align: right;
    } 
    ul li {
     display: inline;
    }

    ul li.default {
     float: left;
    }
    li.nav {
     float: auto;
    }

<ul>
  <li class="default">a</li>
  <li class="default">b</li>
  <li class="nav">c</li>
  <li class="nav">d</li>
</ul>
```